# how to paint on colour nodes

Tags: uv, texture-painting, color, shader-nodes, texture-paint-mode

I wanted to add colour to a character I'm working so I created these nodes for a textured colour on my creature but have a few problems (I'm a complete beginner)
Do I need to apply the colour nodes like you would a mesh because it seems to disappear when I go into different tabs
[image]
I also need to colour things like the eyes and decided I wanted to just use the paint brush tool as that seems easier so can I use that on top? When I try to it doesn't work and this warning appears
[image]
[image]

It seemed like my teacher was able to just draw on her sculpt

Answer (score 1):

To paint on an object you need at least 2 things: unwrap your object (you can choose the *Smart UV Project* mode) and use an *(Texture) Image Texture* node (with a new image) that you plug into the *Base Color* of your *Principled BSDF*. Also use the *UV* output of the *Texture Coordinate*:

[image]

If you want to keep a procedural color as background, you can plug an image with transparent background (alpha 0) into the B input of a *Color > Mix Color*, use the *Alpha* output as factor, and choose the color you want in the A input:

[image]